# Getting inconsistent margins across pages

Tags: vertical-alignment, margins, page

[image]

I'm getting inconsistent margins across pages. The preamble of my document is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside, openright]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% Title Formats for Chapter and Section Headings 
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}[{\titlerule[0.8pt]}]
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\bfseries \centering}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{12pt}{}

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{14pt}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{14 pt}{14pt}
```

I haven't used any other commands to change spacing. The margins do return to the original value on the next page.

Comment: You are loading the class with the `twoside`, which means that even and odd pages have mirrored margins for two-sided printing (so that you get a page spread consisting of an even and an odd page). If you don't want that because you plan to print your document one-sided or don't want to print it at all, remove the option `twoside`.

Comment: I don't want to print but I want each new chapter to start from a new page.

Comment: Since you're loading the `report` document class with the options `openright` and `twoside`, you might as well employ the `book` document class, in which (a) chapters start on a new page automatically and (b) the options `openright` and `twoside` are the defaults.

Comment: Alright. Thanks for the help! Although, do I have to manually change the margins to make the page symmetrical in `twoside`?

Comment: Even in the `report` class `\chapter`s start on a new page, whether you use `twoside` or not. If you remove `twoside` you should get symmetric margins and `\chapter`s still start on a new page. (You probably won't be needing `openright` if you remove `twoside` since there are no left and right pages any more.)

Comment: Cool. Thanks again!